# String variable suddenly becomes a combination of letter and numbers

Tags: java, string, jlabel

I have an array of JLabel **PlayerLabel** and array of **PlayerName** which is intialised the following way

```
        String [] PlayerName;
        PlayerName = new String[4];
        for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            PlayerName[i] = "None1";

        }

JLabel [] PlayerLabel;

PlayerLabel = new JLabel[4];

        for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            String num = Integer.toString(i);
            String output = "Player " + num + " : " + PlayerName;

            PlayerLabel[i] = new JLabel(output);
            PlayerLabel[i].setForeground(Color.white);

        }
```

I would expect the text of my JLabel to be

> Player 1 : None1

Instead I am getting

> Player 1 : java.lang.String;@4e9fd887

the `@15150ef8`part changes to a different combination of numbers and letters everytime i restart the program .

The **PlayerName** is alright when i initialised it
[image]

I have no idea why the **PlayerName** becomes weird when it is added at **output**

[image]

What is happening , How do i resolve this issue ??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you do `+ Playername`, you're printing the *array itself*, not an element in the array. When you try to concatenate an object to a string, the object's `toString()` method is called, and arrays inherit their `toString()` from `Object`:

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

And that's probably not what you wanted.

You might have wanted to do `Playername[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

This will print the certain element of the array at the end of your string:

```
String output = "Player " + num + " : " + PlayerName[i];
```